# How to get value from Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary for which I want to retrieve results matching to those of list

here is what I have done so far

```
         Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> SomeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
        List<int> MyList = new List<int>()
        {

            2,3,4,5
        };

        Dictionary<string, int> internalDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        internalDictionary.Add("two", 2);
        internalDictionary.Add("three", 3);
        internalDictionary.Add("four", 4);
        internalDictionary.Add("five", 5);

        Dictionary<string, int> AnotherDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        AnotherDictionary.Add("six", 6);
        AnotherDictionary.Add("three", 3);
        AnotherDictionary.Add("seven", 7);


        SomeDictionary.Add("Dictionary1", internalDictionary);
        SomeDictionary.Add("Dictionary2", AnotherDictionary);


        var res = from l in MyList
                  select(from q in
                  (from p in
                       (from s in SomeDictionary
                        select s)
                   select p) where q.Value.Equals(l) select q);
```

The value returned is null. what am i Missing ?

I need matching `KeyValuePair` where value matches internal dictionary values.

Comment: well you are comparing `objects` (2,3,4,...) with `strings` (`"2"`, ...) aside from that `from c in col select c == col`

Comment: Yes so What should I do instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var res = from l in MyList
              from q in SomeDictionary
              from w in q.Value
              where w.Value == l
              select w;
```

I get this:

[image: res]

Answer (score 3):

Explanation:

1. Select Many to combine all internal dictionaries into All In One dictionary.
2. List and SelectMany are IEnumerable. So join is possible between to IEnumerable objects.
3. However, List contains string value while IEnumerable object returned from SelectMany has integer value.

So created inner join query with string and integer value after converting integer to string. Refer screencast that might be required output

[Screen cast showing working code](http://screencast.com/t/BGJLz20z)

This Linq snippet may be helpful:

```
var allinone = (from l in MyList
                       join d in SomeDictionary.SelectMany(s => s.Value) on l equals d.Value
                       select d);
```

Comment: What changed? Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: have you even checked this with the compiler? Why should this be helpful? Where is the connection to the question?

Comment: Please refer complete answer.

Comment: What you've added is just a copy of the question. Please tell us what you've changed.

Comment: why all the hate? kyle asked for a query to filter the dictionary and vrluckyin answered with a working query

Comment: well you almost got it - but still you did not explain at all and there is duplication in your code, ...

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic there is no hate - if you have enough rep look at the edit history and you will understand ...

Comment: Explanation: 1. Select Many to combine all internal dictionaries into All In One dictionary. 2. List and SelectMany are IEnumerable. So join is possible between to IEnumerable objects. 3. However, List contains string value while IEnumerable object returned from SelectMany has integer value. So created inner join query with string and integer value after converting integer to string. Refer screencast that might be required output - http://screencast.com/t/BGJLz20z

Comment: I am still confused on accepted answer and my previous answer! There were no explanation! But if someone tried with my previous answer [before any edit] and see the result. I did same thing [solution is different!] like accepted answer. I was tried to be short, neat and clean to the question.